# Migrating Local .Net Identity to Azure ADB2C and Creating the Exact User Id

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In the code below, I created a user on b2c but when I checked the user on azure portal, all fields were correct except for the Id, how can I make azure b2c create an identical user with exact user Id?

```
        private static async Task MigrateUserAsync(GraphServiceClient client, MigratedUser user, string b2cDomainName)
        {
            var userPrincipalName = $"cpim_{Guid.NewGuid()}@{b2cDomainName}";
            await client.Users.Request().AddAsync(new User
            {
                AccountEnabled = true,
                Id = "837b0857-11cb-46ad-a229-4cd8de66d033",
                
                
                DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                GivenName = user.GivenName,
                Surname = user.Surname,
                Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
                {
                    new ObjectIdentity
                    {
                        SignInType = "emailAddress",
                        Issuer = b2cDomainName,
                        IssuerAssignedId = user.Email
                    },
                },

                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    Password="xXx111!!!",
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn=false
                },

                PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration",
            });
        }
```

the user created had a different Id than the one I specified when I created the user. I could not find any documentation addressing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id, objectId, is randomly generated when the user is created in the directory. You cannot provide the objectId.

You could instead add another identity to the identities collection to store the old Id. This would provide a way to look up the account with the old Id.

```cs
new ObjectIdentity
  {
    SignInType = "oldId",
    Issuer = "legacyIdp.com",
    IssuerAssignedId = "<GUID>"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized that after a day of research, so we decided to go with "email" as the unique identifier for our app!